# The LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogon Attribute for more "real-time" logon tracking

Tags: powershell, ldap

What my function does is it uses PowerShell jobs to query for a users lastlogon from every domain controller in the domain.

**Get-LastLogon -Identity USR1**

```
OUTPUT:

Tuesday, March 17, 2020 4:47:27 PM
```

But , but the lastlogontimestamp attribute returns a more current date.  Where am I missing ?

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DC01.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogonTimestamp: 5/12/2020 11:05:24 AM
```

Here is my script:

```
Function Get-LastLogon (){
    [cmdletbinding()]

    Param(
        [alias("UserName","User","SamAccountName","Name","DistinguishedName","UserPrincipalName","DN","UPN")]
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline,Position=0,Mandatory)]
        [string[]]$Identity
    )

    begin{
        $DCList = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers.name
    }

    process{

        foreach($currentuser in $Identity)
        {
            $filter = switch -Regex ($currentuser){
                '=' {'DistinguishedName';break}
                '@' {'UserPrincipalName';break}
                ' ' {'Name';break}
                default {'SamAccountName'}
            }

            Write-Verbose "Checking lastlogon for user: $currentuser"

            foreach($DC in $DCList)
            {
                Write-Verbose "Current domain controller: $DC"
                
                $ad = [ADSI]"LDAP://$dc"

                $searcher = [DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]::new($ad,"($filter=$currentuser)")
                $account = $searcher.findone()
                
                if(!$account)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "No user found with search term '$filter=$currentuser'"
                    continue
                }

                $logon     = $($account.Properties.lastlogon)
                $logontimestamp = $($account.Properties.lastlogontimestamp)

                Write-Verbose "LastLogon          : $([datetime]::FromFileTime($logon))"
                Write-Verbose "LastLogonTimeStamp : $([datetime]::FromFileTime($logontimestamp))"
                
                $logontime = $($logon,$lastlogontimestamp |
                    Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
            
                if($logontime -gt $newest)
                {
                    $newest = $logontime
                }
            }

            if($account)
            {
                switch ([datetime]::FromFileTime($newest)){
                    {$_.year -eq '1600'}{
                        "Never"
                    }
                    default{$_}
                }
            }

            Remove-Variable newest,account,lastlogon,logon,logontime,lastlogontimestamp -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    }

    end{
        Remove-Variable dclist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

**Get-LastLogon -Identity USR1**

```
OUTPUT:

Tuesday, March 17, 2020 4:47:27 PM
```

repadmin /showattr * "CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com" /attrs:lastLogon >c:\temp\lastLogontimeStamp.txt

**LASTLOGON:**

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DC01.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogon: 1/23/2020 11:49:10 AM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DC02.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogon: 7/14/2019 9:27:53 AM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DRDC.contoso.com

DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DCSITE01.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogon: 3/16/2020 4:27:03 PM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DCSITE02.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogon: 3/17/2020 4:47:27 PM
```

repadmin /showattr * "CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com" /attrs:lastLogontimeStamp >c:\temp\lastLogontimeStamp.txt

**LASTLOGONTIMESTAMP:**

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DC01.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogonTimestamp: 5/12/2020 11:05:24 AM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DC02.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogonTimestamp: 5/12/2020 11:05:24 AM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DRDC.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogonTimestamp: 5/12/2020 11:05:24 AM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DCSITE01.contoso.com

```
DN: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogonTimestamp: 5/12/2020 11:05:24 AM
```

Repadmin: running command /showattr against full DC DCSITE02.contoso.com

D

```
N: CN=USR1,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com

    1> lastLogonTimestamp: 5/12/2020 11:05:24 AM
```

Comment: I'm not an Active Directory expert, so it is questionable how much I can help.  Without looking at the code, the first concern I have is that where I work the users have cellphones that connect to our wireless network, and technically those devices are logging in to our network and that requires a domain controller.  In all likelihood, both types of data, all login attempts and all logins on a computer, exist and are available separately.  This may not be an actual problem, just the first thing that comes to mind. I'll do some research.

Comment: I normally don't do anything with user accounts domain controllers, AD, etc... But in a PowerShell 5.1 window on a Win10 system, I tried this `Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "USR1"' -Properties "LastLogonDate"`, only had my user name instead of USR1, and the LastLogonDate property looked correct.  Does this work in your environment? Is this the info you want?

Comment: AFAIK , Lastlogon is updated by the authenticating DC, it is not replicated. Lastlogontimestamp gets evaluated by DCs occasionally and will update, and is replicated. Indeed it can be 14 days past. But the lastlogontimestamp attribute returns a more current date. I'm very confused. I'm querying all domain controllers and get the latest value.  Is it expected behaviour ? or BUG ? I don't understand exactly it.

Comment: As I said, I'm not into AD, so just experimenting.  In a PS 5.1 windows I tried `$AllOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName -Filter *`, and then searched through `$AllOUs`, turns out that my OU was was index 165 in the array.  Tried `$DN = $AllOUs[165].DistinguishedName` and then tried `repadmin /showattr * "CN=user1,$DN" /attrs:lastLogon` with my username instead of `user1` and it gave me all 4 of the domain controllers and a different logon time for each.  The most recent time in the list matched the info I'm getting elsewhere.

Comment: So as you can see , I am using my above script. Is there any missing inside script?

Comment: These dates are almost 3 years old. Is it possible that the domain controller they last authenticated to has been decommissioned in the last 3 years?